# How to get grouped products in a product collection Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection, grouped-products

How can I get only grouped products in a product collection in Magento 2?

is there any filter for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected $productCollectionFactory;


public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    ....
}
```

Now you can use this like,

```
$groupProductCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create() 
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
```